# How to access contextPath in Thymeleaf?

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I  wanted to access contextPath in thymeleaf without setting org.springframework.ui.Model. I configured context path in application.properties file

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are using Thymeleaf, you should be able to use

```
<a th:href="@{/XXX}">Link Name</a>
```

assuming that  has been declared.

I think this does require using SpringTemplateEngine.

Comment: how will i add context path which is configured in application.properties?, this may change in future so i cant add static values

Answer (score 9):

A url expression of `@{/}` gives you your complete context... For example, if you have:

```
# application.properties
server.contextPath=/your/context
```

Then you can use

```
<div th:text="@{/}" />
or
<div th:text="${#request.contextPath}" />
both of which will output
<div>/your/context/</div>
```

Comment: can i give like ' th:href="@{/user-registration}"   '? will it automatically add my context path  like <a  href="/my-context-path/user-registration"> link</a>

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the context path from application.properties using @ConfigurationProperties with a new class for properties like AppProperties.java.

You can then autowire this properties class in the class where you will be setting ThymeLeaf parameters and then set this parameter in Thymeleaf context and fetch it accordingly in the html file ..

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "com.test")
public class AppProperties{

private String contextPath;
}
```

Setting in Template Engine

```
@Service
public class MailContentBuilder {

private TemplateEngine templateEngine;

@Autowired
public MailContentBuilder(TemplateEngine templateEngine) {
    this.templateEngine = templateEngine;
}

public String build(CodeRequest codeRequest, String lang) {
    Context context = new Context();
    context.setVariable("footerFile", "footer_" + lang);
    context.setVariable("customerInfo", codeRequest);
    context.setVariable("imageLogo", "cid:" + Constants.LOGO);
    context.setVariable("imageBorder", "cid:" + Constants.LEFT_BORDER);
    context.setVariable("imageFooter", "cid:" + Constants.LOGO_FOOTER);
    return templateEngine.process("template", context);
}
}
```

HTML changes:

```
<div th:replace="${contextPath}"></div>
```

Comment: where to set Template Engine?

Comment: I have edited my answer to include the MailContentBuilder class using TemplateEngine for Thymeleaf email content generation .. you can check this ..

Comment: Welcome !! You may consider this: stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

If you need the contextPath in Javascript, you can do the following:

```
<!--
  th:inline="javascript" prepares the script to allow "JSON data injection"
  via [[${modelParameterName}]] or [[@{urlPath}]].
  This is called "JavaScript natural templates" in Thymeleaf.
  By using comments around the part to be inlined we can provide default values.
-->
<script th:inline="javascript">
  const contextpath = /*[[@{/}]]*/ "/";
  // ... do something with contextPath, e.g., use it with axios ...
</script>
```

---

Here we see that we want to inline `[[@{/}]]` into JavaScript, which refers to the root of our web application (i.e., the contextPath).

---

Thymeleaf documentation: [JavaScript natural templates](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#javascript-natural-templates)